# react js, hooks, a single div to receive all components sections

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I would like to know if it is possible and how to do this:

in my page structure I'll have one header
one navbar and one container for content only
and a footer

in my navbar i will have my sections like:

home, about, products

and I would like these sections to be in my content container so when clicking one of these options does not reload the page but only the content

at the moment I have it

my app route:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>

    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

my HomePage

```
export default function Cards() {

    return (
        <>
        <Header/>
        <Navigation/>
        <Container maxWidth="lg" >
            <div className="contents">
            <Products/>
            </div>
        </Container>
        </>
    );
}
```

I wanted all section components to be called only in div content

and my navbar:

```
export default function Navigation() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar} >
          <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Toolbar >
 <Button  className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false"  color="secondary">
   Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised"  disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
        </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    );
}
```

Would it be possible to do this using redux?

example with image:
[image]

if i click on home 1

only the component where the products are would be changed and not the full page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your components that need to be rendered on every page outside the switch.

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Navigation/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much, could you just give me one more help? in my appbar I have my buttons that would redirect to the pages that will go to content how would i do that?

Comment: You can use Link component from the react router package, it would look like this `<Link to="/path"/>Go to path</Link>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need redux to do this, just elevate your header, footer, and navbar components above to where your routes are defined. By doing this you only change your app content when your route changes, and you can use the `location` object to reflect updates to the header, navbar, and footer.

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Navigation/>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>

      <Footer/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much,
could you just give me one more help?

in my appbar
I have my buttons that would redirect to the pages that will go to content
how would i do that?